# Images,.js are not found in mvc 4 with parameterized action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning MVC from internet and developing one project.I have an action method ViewProfile(int id)`in controller.When i called this action from view`@Html.ActionLink(item.RegID, "ViewProfile", "UserDetails", new { id = item.PersonalID }, null)
`then view is displayed without images and js are not working.But when i make action ViewProfile without parameter then it works fine when i call it from view`
@Html.ActionLink(item.RegID, "ViewProfile", "UserDetails")` it works fine.

```
  public ActionResult ViewProfile(int id)
        {

            var result = from m in db.PersonalDetails
                         join d in db.HoroscopeDetails on m.PersonalID equals d.PersonalID
                         join b in db.AddressDetails on m.PersonalID equals b.PersonalID
                         join f in db.FamilyDetails on m.PersonalID equals f.PersonalID
                         join ed in db.EducationalDetails on m.PersonalID equals ed.PersonalID
                         join exp in db.Expectations on m.PersonalID equals exp.PersonalID
                         where m.PersonalID == id
                         select new EditModel
                         {
                             PersonalID = m.PersonalID,
                             BloodGroup = m.BloodGroup,

                             Complexion = m.Complexion,
                             Diet = m.Diet,
                             Disability = m.Disability,
                             DisabilityDetails = m.DisabilityDetails,
                             DOB = m.DOB,
                             FirstName = m.FirstName,
                             Height = m.Height,
                             LastName = m.LastName,
                             Lens = m.Lens,
                             MaritalStatus = m.MaritalStatus,
                             MidName = m.MidName,
                             Personality = m.Personality,
                             ProfilePic = m.ProfilePic,
                             Spectacles = m.Spectacles,
                             subcast = m.subcast,
                             Weight = m.Weight,
                             BirthPlace = d.BirthPlace,
                             BirthTime = d.BirthTime,
                             Charan = d.Charan,
                             Gan = d.Gan,
                             GotraORDevak = d.GotraORDevak,
                             Mangal = d.Mangal,
                             Nadi = d.Nadi,
                             Nakshtra = d.Nakshtra,
                             Rashi = d.Rashi,
                             Mobile1 = b.Mobile1,
                             EmailId = b.EmailId,
                             FullAddress = b.FullAddress,
                             Mobile2 = b.Mobile2,
                             Phone1 = b.Phone1,
                             Phone2 = b.Phone2,
                             PinCode = b.PinCode,
                             Brother = f.Brother,
                             FamilyEstate = f.FamilyEstate,
                             Father = f.Father,
                             FatherFullName = f.FatherFullName,
                             InterCast = f.InterCast,
                             IntercastAny = f.IntercastAny,
                             MamasName = f.MamasName,
                             MarriedBrother = f.MarriedBrother,
                             MarriedSister = f.MarriedSister,
                             Mother = f.Mother,
                             NativeDistrict = f.NativeDistrict,
                             ParentCity = f.ParentCity,
                             ParentOccupation = f.ParentOccupation,
                             Relatives = f.Relatives,
                             Sister = f.Sister,
                             Education = ed.Education,
                             EducationDetails = ed.EducationDetails,
                             Income = ed.Income,
                             IncomeType = ed.IncomeType,
                             Occupation = ed.Occupation,
                             OccupationCity = ed.OccupationCity,
                             Divorcee = exp.Divorcee,
                             expEducation = exp.Education,
                             ExpectedCast = exp.ExpectedCast,
                             ExpHeight = exp.ExpHeight,
                             ExpOccupationIncome = exp.ExpOccupationIncome,
                             Mangalik = exp.Mangal,
                             MaxAgeDiff = exp.MaxAgeDiff,
                             PreferCity = exp.PreferCity,
                             taluka = f.Taluka,

                         };
            ViewBag.List = result;
            return View("ViewDetails");
        }

 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: How you have configured **routes** ??? Plz post that code also...

Comment: is there any problem in routing????

Comment: Problem is solved.I have added another route in Route.config which maps url url: "ViewProfile/{id}"